# Can I use Amazon Lambda to host my action?

Tags: actions-on-google

I’m building my first action following the documentation at [Build apps for the Google Assistant with Actions on Google](http://developers.google.com/actions), and I noticed the samples recommend App Engine as the hosting solution. Do I have to use App Engine or can I use non-Google owned hosting, such as Amazon Lambda?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use any hosting platform for the webhook of your action. For your action, you need a web server to accept incoming HTTP POST webhook requests and then respond with a JSON payload. If you use Node.js, Google has developed a convenient client library which you can obtain via NPM as ‘actions-on-google’.

Comment: To add, if you specifically want to use AWS Lambda, you can use AWS API Gateway to 'expose' your lambda function via https. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

The closest natural description for "Lambda" is cloud function, so any host that allows you to write functions and execute them over http(s) is fine.

I just sent a POST with my function to https://01234567890.firebaseio.com/.json and used that firebase as my webhook.